# Scramble/Jumble Together

Tags: meaning, difference

> "Devastated Indian bands then faced the daunting task of literally
>   reinventing themselves without benefit of accumulated wisdom or kin
>   networks. The decimation and forced migration of native peoples
>   sometimes **scrambled them together** in wholly new ways. The Catawba
>   nation of the southern piedmont region, for example, was formed from
>   splintered remnants of several different groups uprooted by the shock
>   of the Europeans’ arrival." 
>   From the American Pageant by Thomas A. Bailey

According to Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary:

> Jumble: to cause (things) to be mixed together in a way that is not
>   neat or orderly
>     Scramble: to put (parts of something) in the wrong order

I understand here "scramble"means tribes, which were not supposed to be together, 
were together because of external circumstances.

Would "jumble" be better than "scramble" here? Please comment.

Comment: Scramble also can figuratively imply mixing things together like a scrambled eggs!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on it ?  How does it fit the context?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use mixed or jumbled in this context. As the dictionary definition you have given states: scramble implies the wrong order. This implies that the objects (or in this case people) you're referring to would need a specific order in the first place.

Comment: I do think people have a specific order before they mix. That perhaps explains why "scramble" is better?

Comment: From the context I would say they were segregated or grouped rather than ordered though. I may have misunderstood the paragraph. Don't get me wrong, I think scrambled does work, it just doesn't quite sound like the best word in the context when I read the sentence out loud.